# Matlab - Fast Computation of Truncated SVD / PCA

Tags: matlab, svd

I'm working with a Matlab codebase wherein I'm attempting to solve `A*c = b` by approximating the (square) matrix `A` with its `q` largest principal components (basically using the rank-`q` PCA approximation of `A`).  I'm currently doing that by writing `c = pinv(A, tol)*b`, where `tol` is the `q`th largest singular value of `A`.  This works; however, even if `q=1`, the method is slow, because I think Matlab's `pinv` is computing the full SVD of `A` under the hood when something simpler like power method should suffice.

Is there a more appropriate/faster Matlab routine for approximating the inverse of `A` based on its truncated/incremental SVD?  For example, is there a way to get just the largest `q` singular vectors/values of `A`, without computing any other singular vectors/values?  I have been computing the full `[U,S,V]=svd(A)` and then taking the columns/values I want, but that is not efficient.

I'm aware I could implement the power method and deflation by myself -- and may end up doing that -- but my specific question is about the most computationally efficient way to complete this task using built-in Matlab routines (and as few as possible).  If Matlab has no good built-in ways to do this I'm open to suggestions of third-party Matlab packages as well which would provide this functionality efficiently; e.g. I've seen [IncPACK2](https://github.com/andrewssobral/imtsl/blob/master/libs/IncPACK2/seqkl.m) which seems at a glance to do the right thing (though it's no longer maintained...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pseudoinverse can be computed using the SVD $A = USV^\top$ by:
$$
A^+ = V\Sigma^+ U^\top
$$
where $\Sigma^+$ is formed from $\Sigma$ by taking the reciprocal of all the non-zero elements. With that in mind, you could use MATLAB's `svds` function as follows:

```
[U,S,V] = svds(A,k); 
Ainv = V*diag(1./diag(S))*U';
```

Here `k` refers to the rank and `svds` computes only a subset of singular values and vectors. Due to the use of Krylov subspace methods, it also allows to limit other factors such as subspace-dimension.